# How to put a scheduled task on GreenPlum?

Tags: greenplum

As the question listed, I would like to set up a series of monthly/daily tasks on Greenplum server.

However, I tried to search online but can not find a way.

May anyone gives me a hint?? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the crontab utility for the gpadmin user to set up scheduled tasks specific to Greenplum.

Jim McCann
Pivotal

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, to be honest I'm new to this and do not familiar with it. So would you be so kind to provide more details on how to use crontab to setup scheduled task, do I need to install pg_cron??

Comment: crontab is part of the Linux operating system.   Do a "man crontab".  You want to set up a user crontab.  Here is a link to a good overview:   https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

Comment: furthermore, does it means that I would need to type in script including psql commend to do a scheduled task??

Comment: Yes, most people use shell scripts.  Be sure the path to all the Greenplum executables is in the script at the start so it can find everything.

Comment: It can be a shell script which in turn executes "psql". If it's a simple command, you can place the psql call directly into the cronjob. Or you can use any other scripting language which can connect to PostgreSQL or Greenplum, and which then executes the SQL commands you want to run.

Answer (score 1):

pg_task job scheduler now supports greenplum and postgres